# Translation not working with Preview-Stories in Open Graph Timeline-View

Tags: facebook, internationalization, translation, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

We are working on an app that has the locales german and english. Our app creates open graph actions like "[User] offered [Object] on [App]".

I have translated all our strings in facebooks translation app, my facebook account is set to german and our app runs with the default locale german.

When we post to the graph, the unique og:url for the action/object links to a site with the following html:

```
<meta content='de_DE' property='og:locale'>
<meta content='de_DE' property='og:locale:alternate'>
<meta content='en_US' property='og:locale:alternate'>
```

Our app is able to serve the content in different languages when called with the locale-param, e.g. "?locale=en-US" or "?locale=de-DE".

I have seen correctly translated text in the ticker, that seems to work. Also, the preview popups that come up from the ticker messages are correctly translated.

Now the Problem: the aggregation preview in the Timeline does always show the english action types. But when i click into the aggregation and i only see the App's "All time" aggregation, there the translation is correct.

https://skitch.com/florian2/gse8h/the-problem
[Picture 1] so thats my problem, that "searched" should be a "sucht", that "offered" should be "bietet an".

https://skitch.com/florian2/gse1n/the-problem-4
[Picture 2] here you can see a line from my activity log, that should be in german, too. The second line is from the translation tool and looks like that it should be the correct translation for the log-line, right?

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood it, the translation strings need to be approved somehow by the community through the [translation app](https://www.facebook.com/?sk=translations).

Answer (score 0):

as i can see from the first screenshot, the translation in the second one is wrong. It should be something like

> searched {flat1}

The aggregation do not have {name} and {Flatorious} in it.

Greets

P.S.: Hugo, if you are the dev or admin of the App, you do not need to approve the translations. Only if someone third party is translating.